# Set builder notation for this set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need set builder notation for a set.
Set under consideration is:

$$\{m,n,o,p\}$$
What I suggest is:

$$\{x\colon x\in\{m,n,o,p\}\}$$
Any suggestions is it correct?

Comment: Yeah, it is great. Why not $\{x\ |\ x\in\{x\ |\ x\in \{m,n,o,p\}\}\}$.

Comment: Someone who sees it will wonder: why is he not just writing $\left\{ m,n,o,p\right\} $?

Comment: @drhab agree but I found in exercise so have to do it.

Comment: If you really  *have* to then you also choose for $\left\{ x\mid x=m\vee x=n\vee x=o\vee x=p\right\} $

Comment: A notation like $\left\{ x\mid x\in A\right\} $ for $A$ doesn't
really look good and it isn't surprising that mathematicians make
fun of it. The comment of String is an example of that.

Comment: @drhab got it after a bit of taunts :)

Comment: @String : Sarcasm may be hazardous.

Comment: @Everyone: Sorry, I kind of went with it finding it amusing that the idea could be extended indefinitely $$\small\{x\ |\ x\in\{x\ |\ x\in\{x\ |\ x\in\{x\ |\ x\in\{x\ |\ x\in\{x\ |\ x\in\{x\ |\ x\in\{x\ |\ x\in\{m,n,o,p\}\}\}\}\}\}\}\}\}$$

Comment: @String pardon my ignorance but how can set which consists of alphabets can be expressed by using set builder notation?

Comment: @Labeeb: That is ok! The verbal description could be "letters alhabetically from m to p".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: How would you verbally describe those letters? What do they have in common? Given a verbal description, you can then describe the set with set-builder notation as $$\{x\mid x\text{ [fits verbal description]}\}.$$

For example, I could describe the set $\{\text{red, blue, yellow}\}$ by $$\{x\mid x\text{ is a primary color}\}.$$

Comment: concluding can it be said that if nothing is common then we can't use approach of "x is a primary color" ?

Comment: If we can't think of a way to describe all of them simultaneously, then no, we can't. However, drhab showed us in the comments above that we can pretty much always do this for finite sets. What *do* $m,n,o,p$ have in common, though?